# mysql error de mysql.sock

Tags: mysql, moodle

Hola amigos espero que esten bien todos resulta que tengo un error en la base de datos resulta que no puedo acceder a mi base de datos con mi usuario root, ni con el usuario que utilizo en moodle y el servicio de mysql no se esta ejecuando, tiene un error y cuando trato ingresar tambien genera un error esto lo que pasa con el status mysql:

```
root@mv-smowl-test:~# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-05-20 19:19:12 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 9716 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
  Process: 9691 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 20 19:19:12 mv-smowl-test systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

cuando trato de ingresar como root u otro usuario me sale el siguiente error:

```
root@mv-smowl-test:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

root@mv-smowl-test:~# mysql -u moodle -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

espero saber que paso o como puedo salvar mi base de datos gracias amigos

Comment: ¿Intentaste reiniciar todo? ¿El error de arriba sale siempre? ¿Tienes MySQL bien instalado?

Comment: ya reinicie el servidor y apache pues instale nuevamente mysql-server y dice que esta en su ultima version, me preocupa es que pierda la info de la base de datos